# Formula with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

There exist any kind formula for the next sum?

$$
\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i}i^\alpha
$$
with $\alpha$ an integer.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3091196/42969

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{0 \le i \le n} \binom{n}{i} z^i
    &= (1 + z)^n \\
  z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \sum_{0 \le i \le n} \binom{n}{i} z^i
    &= \sum_{0 \le i \le n} \binom{n}{i} i z^i \\
    &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} (1 + z)^n \\
    &= z n (1 + z)^{n - 1}
\end{align*}$

If you evaluate the last expression at $z = 1$ you get:

$\begin{align*}
   1 \cdot n \cdot 2^{n - 1}
     &= \sum_{0 \le i \le n} \binom{n}{i} i
\end{align*}$

Repeat the above $\alpha$ times, and you are set. I don't think there is a simple, general formula.